# ROC Curve - How to deal with overflow?

Tags: scikit-learn, roc

I'm trying to calculate the ROC curve and the AUC of a binary logistic regression from scratch, without using third party methods like `sklearn.metrics.roc_curve`, to see if I really understand what it's about.

However, I'm having some issue, probably overflow related, when computing *TPR*, true positive rate, and *FPR*, false positive rate. Let `M = confusion_matrix(y_true,pred)`; the following code seem to be problematic:

```
fpr = M[1,0]/(M[0,0]+M[1,0])
tpr = M[1,1]/(M[1,1]+M[0,1])
```

For threshold very close to either zero or one, one of the denominators goes to zero.
If I force `fpr,tpr=1,1` every time `M[1,1]+M[0,1]=0`, the ROC curve obtained looks like this [image]

Any ideas on what I could do differently?

Comment: Before worrying about thresholds close to 0 or 1, you should figure out why your code gives different results from sklearn for the same threshold value

Comment: The denominators are constant and not impacted by the choice of threshold. Clearly your computations are wrong.